# problem in installing Ros in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, ros

i am new to ubuntu 20.04 and i have a problem while installing ROS1

```
sudo apt install curl # if you haven't already installed curl

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi

libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libva-wayland2

Use 'sudo apt autoremove to remove them.

libcurl4

The following additional packages will be installed:

curl

The following NEW packages will be installed:

The following packages will be upgraded:

libcurl4

1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 288 not upgraded.

Need to get 161 kB/396 kB of archives.

After this operation, 417 kB of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

Abort.
```

Comment: First install all pending updates using the update manager

Comment: i am doing it  by the command sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: i did it what should i do next

Comment: Now follow the commands to install ROS, as you were doing previously.